# How to get the value user typed in on a search bar in android and use that value in all other activities

Tags: android

In one of my activities in my android app, I am going to have a search bar and then no matter what the user types in there, I need to get that String and use it in all of my other activities.

Does anyone know how we can do that? Basically I need this value to be accessible in each activity. I've looked online, but I haven't found anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear on your requirement.

As far as I understood, you want to pass your search query from your search activity to all other activities.

You can get the search query entered from ' onQueryTextChange ' callback method, assign that entered query to a global string and pass it to other activites via bundle.

Comment: Yeah so basically they will type in something into that search bar and then I need to get that string that they type in and basically use that value in all other activities and in those activities it'll go into a query for getting information out of my existing database. So basically to do that, like you said, I can use the onQueryTextChange method and then put that into a global string variable and then can access that in all my activities and put that into a query correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have listener for that see following code

```
your_searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
                {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
                {

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

In onQueryTextSubmit method's parameter query is your text of search view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static member to store that query:

```
public class DATA {
    public static String lastQuery = "";
}
```

Set it at query events:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String textQuery) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String textQuery) {
            DATA.lastQuery = textQuery;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You can use it anywhere in your app:

```
...
String str = "Last query was: " + DATA.lastQuery;
...
```

Comment: Ok, so basically I put that code that you have above there into the activity which contains the searchView and then for each activity that I want to use that value that the user entered into the searchView, I just need to put the  DATA.lastQuery line that you have there and then store it into a string variable in each activity and then use that variable to do whatever right?

Comment: If that's what you need, yes. Of course, you can use the constant directly, that was just an example. i.e. if you want to display the string in a textview you can just: `myTextView.setText(DATA.lastQuery)`